# How do I get tabs to copy properly in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, language-agnostic

When I copy and paste (for example) a function, the first line is tabbed correctly, but every line after is tabbed back too much. While this is at most a minor annoyance, I'd still like to fix it. I can't seem to find a setting that controls this, but if there is one, I would like to know. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just navigate to Source > Format and click on format it automatically format the whole function.

Shortcut : Alt+Shift+f

Make sure you have done all formatting . Link for detail formatting : https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/formatting_tabs_and_indents

Comment: http://netbeanside61.blogspot.in/2008/04/top-10-netbeans-ide-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: This works, but it places the stuff after the first line one space ahead of the first line, rather than a tab ahead. Do you know if it's possible to do that?

Comment: Thanks. Go to Tools>Options>Editor>Formatting. Select language and update Indents
Also you can format your code quicky using ALT+F command